# Preview in list items is off

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, editor

In the SO editor, the preview for various types of text inside list items does not match the end results.

Take this for instance. It is fine on the screen now, but when you edit...

1. This is a normal paragraph. Looks OK.

   ```html
       <p>This is a stacksnippet.
           <span>All but the first line is indented too much.</span>
       </p>
   ```

   And this is supposed to be a normal line of text, but it looks like a code block.

Is it possible to correct these problems?

Comment: Remove `<!-- language: lang-html -->` and the problem seems to go away ...

Comment: Only for the snippet itself; not for the paragraph following after, that looks like a code block. Also, if the snippet contains CSS, removing the html comment removes the separator between the HTML and CSS blocks.

Comment: The preview tends to be outsync of how markdown gets interpreted down the road, you may have a PR https://github.com/balpha/pagedown

Comment: @Braiam Not sure what you mean. What is a PR? What does the link show? And how does it explain the differences between preview and eventual post?

Comment: PR = Pull Request. The source code of the editor, including the previewer. Well, the post html is rendered with the [commonmark](http://commonmark.org/) implementation on server side, while the client side uses pagedown's renderer. This is not novel either, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298409/error-with-code-formatter#comment216588_298409

Comment: @Braiam that is an interesting claim about commonmark. Any (un)official link(s) to support that?

Comment: @rene for one the bug I cited reveals that the indentation rules to get pre/code blocks changed to behave as CommonMark specifies. Another would be this very same post.

Comment: @Braiam I would say that is just a PageDown bug server-side....

Comment: @rene PageDown is the client-side editor, based on WDM. Is not used to render the server side of stuff. ["While on the Stack Exchange sites PageDown is exclusively used on the client site (on the server side, MarkdownSharp is our friend),"](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown)

Comment: @Braiam Ok, you win, still not commonmark ;)

Comment: @rene well, it's [consistent with observations](http://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/140/help.png), I would say.

Comment: I'm currently writing a rather lengthy answer that makes heavy use of Stack Snippets in lists, and the live preview is pretty much unusable as a result of this. If I can't trust the editor to preview my answer correctly, I'm not going to be very confident about posting it. (I'd be happy to post my answer without *any* Stack Snippets as doing so will make it much easier to skim, but *someone* is going to try and edit them in later and potentially destroy the list formatting in the process.)

Comment: Possibly related: [Stack Snippets delimiters are being parsed too eagerly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284254/stack-snippets-delimiters-are-being-parsed-too-eagerly)